# Trying to Select Single Value from Joomla 2.5 Database

Tags: database, object, select, joomla, module

I am trying to determine if a certain module is published or not.  Here is the script I am using to query the database:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('published');
$query->from('#__modules');
$query->where('module = mod_modulename');     

$options = $db->loadObjectList();
```

When I try to `return $options;` I am getting a blank screen.  Why won’t this just tell me if it is a `1` or `0` value and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

---

Well I have it cleared up that my query was incomplete, so that you all for those notes.  I now am having trouble getting the values that are loaded in the object list to print on the screen.  I have tried `return` `print_r` and a `foreach` loop but nothing is showing up.  Is there a way to test and find out if the object list is empty?  It should not be as I see the value in the database table...

Comment: You're query is incomplete. Have a look at the Joomla Docs: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot adding the following

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

So completed your query would be

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('published');
$query->from('#__modules');
$query->where('module = mod_modulename'); 

$db->setQuery($query); //this is what you forgot 

$options = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Edit: You also don't need to set $db as reference anymore (&)

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have adjusted it, but I am still unable to print the value of `published` on the screen.  I have tried `return $options` but it is still blank.  I guess I am now asking how I can print the values that are loaded in the object list.

Comment: I have determined that it is something to do with `$query->where('module = mod_modulename');` that is breaking my call.

Comment: Well in the end I found that I had to change the where to `$query->where($db->quoteName('module')." = ".$db->quote($modulename));`  Thanks again.